# Why shell command swipe not working in webview Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try make swipe in area webview so:

```
Process su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("input swipe 200 600 200 550");
```

I wait that will be swipe up, but nothing working and why?
becouse when I tap my finger in input field in webview and invoke shell command for input text - its work, input text so:

```
public void simulateText(string text)
        {
            Process process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("input text "+text);
        }
```

why its work for imput text and not work for swipe?

p.s. swipe no work if I invoke shell from other thread in main thred so:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Process su = null;
    su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("input swipe 200 200 200 950");
    su.WaitFor();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

}
```

if invoke without MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread all work

Comment: There is a difference between text and parameters.  When it is working input is the command and everything else is a string.  When it is not working input is the command and you have parameters like arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4.

Comment: I've read your question. When user swipes, you need to manually refresh the webview. For details, you may refer to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489411/swipe-refresh-not-working-in-xamarin-android-webview".

Comment: problem was with multithreading

Comment: Is your problem in the main thread or other threads or "MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread", I want to confirm with you. Thanks.